# django testing http get replaces args

Tags: python, django

Django replaces my arguments by others during my tests for no apparent reason:

```
client = Client()
print(reverse('search_manufacturer')) # prints /search/manufacturer
client.get(reverse('search_manufacturer'), dict(q=str(uuid4())))`
```

results in me getting :

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'show_manufacturer' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'manufacturer_id': 5}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Where is manufacturer_id comming from?

my url patern is :

```
url(r'^manufacturer$', views.search_manufacturer, name='search_manufacturer')
```

If I call `client.get(reverse('search_manufacturer')` it works fine, but it is not what I would like to test

Comment: Are you sure that this is the test that is failing? in error message there is `show_manufacturer`, not `search_manufacturer`. Please post full traceback.

Comment: You are trying to pass `{'manufacturer_id': 5}` to `'search_manufacturer'` view and your regex `r'^manufacturer$'` isn't waiting any.

Comment: @vishes_shell no I am not, I am giving it an a query with an uuid, I don't know where the id is comming from

Comment: @GwynBleidD I did not see that, but it is this test that fail, a few lines above the tracebach I have `django.request: ERROR: Internal Server Error: /search/manufacturer`
And it is this line that is indicated in the traceback

Comment: @EdmondLafay so this error is not from reverse in your test, but from reverse in your view that test is calling. Reverse in test is working fine.

Comment: @GwynBleidD Arf of course you are right! Two hours lost for not reading correctly : (
Thank you so much